# @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss popping to root instead of previous screen

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I am working on a SwiftUI project that has a loginView (Root view embedded in NavigationStack). When I push to registration screen (Screen A) using .navigationDestination(...) modifier and then to another screen (Screen B). When I want to pop to the previous screen (Screen A) from (Screen B) it navigates me to the root (login screen) instead of Screen (B) my code:

NOTE* When I am using NavigationLink for pushing then its working fine. but NavigationLink is deprecated and Apple suggest to use NavigationDestination modifier.

```swift
// LoginView (Root view)

struct LoginView: View {

    @State var moveToScreenA: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {

                Button {
                    self.moveToScreenA = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Registration")
                }
            })
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $moveToScreenA) {
                ScreenA()
            }
        }
    }
}

// Screen A
struct ScreenA: View {

    @State var moveToScreenB: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {

                Button {
                    self.moveToScreenB = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            })
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $moveToScreenB) {
                ScreenB()
            }
        }
    }
}

// Screen B
struct ScreenB: View {

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {

                Button {
                    self.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(.BACK_DARK)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a single `NavigationStack` here, on `LoginView`, then use `NavigationPath` to navigate to the sub-views. Try this:

```swift
struct LoginView: View {
    @State var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
                Button {
                    path.append("A")
                } label: {
                    Text("Registration")
                }
            })
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { string in
                if string == "A" {
                    ScreenA(path: $path)
                } else {
                    ScreenB(path: $path)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Root")
        }
    }
}
```

Then remove `NavigationStack` outer from ScreenA and ScreenB. Use `navigationDestination` for concrete type to distinguish the correct destination.

```swift
struct ScreenA: View {

    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
            Button {
                path.append("B")
            } label: {
                Text("Next")
            }
        })
        .navigationTitle("Screen A")
    }
}

struct ScreenB: View {

    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
            Button {
                path = Navigation() //<- back to the root
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "star")
            }
        })
        .navigationTitle("Screen B")
    }
}
```

---

Example for navigation destination with another type in sub view.

```swift
struct ScreenA: View {

    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, content: {
            Button {
                path.append(true)
            } label: {
                Text("Next")
            }
        })
        .navigationDestination(for: Bool.self) { _ in
             ScreenB(path: $path)    
        }
        .navigationTitle("Screen A")
    }
}
```

Comment: It means our navigation destination would be at single place (at Root) ? ... It will not make it weird to place all destination cases in root view ?

Comment: It's quite correct. In the example above, I used the same path data as `String.self`. So if you put `.navigationDestination` in ScreenA, the same `String.self`. It will still take destination from `LoginView`. If you want to handle navigation destination, i.e from A->B, you can change path data to another type like `path.append(true)`. Then declare `ScreenB(path: $path)` inside content closure from `navigationDestination` in ScreenA

Comment: Using this solution how we will go back to root view from Screen B ?

Comment: I added an example for your circumstance. You may want to take a look.

Comment: And also back to root from Screen B.

Comment: #son How I can bind data from screen A to Screen B If I keep all the destination in Login View ? and one thing more .. Some time I also want to send some data back to screen via completion block, How it could be achieve ?

Comment: We have `@State` and `@Binding` to do these things, or NavigationPath can contain generic types itself. For more details, I think you should ask another question.

Comment: Thanks I done with it ... using navigation path